# How to limit the textarea size

Tags: smartclient

I need to limit the textarea to **4** characters...

my current javascript

```
{
    name : "pin",
    title : "PIN",
    align:"center",
    textArea:"isc.TextArea.setCharacterWidth(4)"
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I do that please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following methods both on [TextAreaItem](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextAreaItem.html) and [TextItem](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextItem.html):

```
    text.setEnforceLength(true);
    text.setLength(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TextAreaItem](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextAreaItem.html) field of smartgwt to create multi-line text area.
To restrict the number of characters for this field, [setLength](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextAreaItem.html#setLength(java.lang.Integer)) can be used.

For example:

```
private TextAreaItem text = new TextAreaItem("pin", "PIN");
text.setLength(4);
text.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
```